# Genetic algorithms: Uniform crossover in just a part of genotype

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I need to implement a "uniform crossover"  genetic operator.

Edit: I realized that it is normal to have duplicates (because of random exchange) if a number appears in both individuals.
So I I added this:

```
            if(anyDuplicate(p0_genome,minIndex) || anyDuplicate(p1_genome,minIndex)){
                                //rollback: swap again
                                swap(p0_genome,p1_genome,i);
                            }
```

**but it stills create duplicates (most of time of the gene in position minIndex (which is excluded from the cycle!!!) . Of course I tested the function anyDuplicate,and it works very well**

I tried with this code

```
> Note: Individual 1 and 2 have the same length but a different number
> of valid bits.
> 
> Foe example: genotype length (of both individuals) = 10 ,
> representation as numbers from 1 to 10 without anyone repeated,the
> start delimiter is 1 and the end delimiter should be 2. Not used genes
> are = 0
> 
> individual 1(p0_genome) = {1,4,5,3,2,0,0,0,0,0}
> individual 2(p1_genome) = {1,4,6,3,8,2,0,0,0,0}
```

**Desideres output:**

```
Individual 1(p0_genome): **1** <some genes ALL DIFFERENTS> **2** 0,0,0,.....
Individual 2(p1_genome): **1** <some genes ALL DIFFERENTS> **2** 0,0,0,.....
```

**Main Code:**

```
            int indexOfLastP0 = findLast(p0_genome,gl); // last valid bit (the one = 2) of first individual
            int indexOfLastP1 = findLast(p1_genome,gl); // last valid bit (the one = 2) of second individual

            int minIndex = Math.min(indexOfLastP0,indexOfLastP1); // last valid bit of the "smaller" of the inviduals

    // Building sons
  /* exchange bit without considering delimiters bit (1 and 2)
   and according to the smaller individual */
            int threshold = 0.60;

    for (int i=1; i<minIndex; i++) {
        if (Math.Random()>threshold) {
            swap(p0_genome,p1_genome,i);
        }
    // when exiting the loop the remaining of genes remain the same
```

**Swap code:**

```
    public void swap(int[] array1, int[] array2 ,int i){
        int aux=array1[i];
        if (array2[i]!=2){
        array1[i]=array2[i];
                }
        if (aux!=2){
        array2[i]=aux;
                }
```

**anyDuplicate() code:**

```
 public boolean anyDuplicate(int[] genoma,int min){
        for (int i=0;i<=min;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<=min;j++){
               if (genoma[i]==genoma[j] && i!=j){
                  return true;
               }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**findLast code:**

```
    public int findLast(int[] mgenome,int genotypeLength){
        int k=1; // 1 element is not considered
        while (k<genotypeLength && mgenome[k]!=0){
            k++;
        }
        return k-1; // **I also tried returning k;**
    }
```

The problem is that **I get a lot of duplicates numbers in both individuals**

I also tried with a "duplicate"**(arraycopy from a parent to a child)** of "fathers":

```
    // Creating sons genotypes
    int [] s0_genome = new int[gl];
    int [] s1_genome = new int[gl];
    // Building sons
          int threshold = 0.60;
    for (int i=0; i<minIndex; i++) {
        if (Math.Random()>threshold)) {
            s0_genome[i] = p1_genome[i];
            s1_genome[i] = p0_genome[i];
        }
        else {
            s0_genome[i] = p0_genome[i];
            s1_genome[i] = p1_genome[i];
        }
             for (int i=minIndex; i<10; i++) {
               // copy what's left
            s0_genome[i] = p0_genome[i];
            s1_genome[i] = p1_genome[i];
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for any hint!

Comment: just as a side note, Math.Random is more biased and inefficient compared to Random. id suggest that you make use of the Random class instead.

Comment: Or better yet, use a pure-random generator based on /dev/random or the like; any PRNG will eventually result in patterns which may cause unexpected yet subtle things to happen.

Comment: Where is the code for `swap()`? What do you mean by duplicate and what  would the desired outcome look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you try swapping once, and if either of the resulting genomes contains duplicate values, you try swapping again. If there are still duplicates after the second try, you give up. This is not efficient, and the longer your genomes are, the more unlikely this is to work.

**Solution A**: You could try only doing a swap if the swapped value is not already in the target genome. That would give a swap function like this:

```
public void swap(int[] array1, int[] array2 ,int i){
    int aux=array1[i];
    if (array2[i]!=2 && !Arrays.asList(array1).contains(array2[i]){
    array1[i]=array2[i];
            }
    if (aux!=2 && !Arrays.asList(array2).contains(array1[i]){
    array2[i]=aux;
            }
```

The problem with this is that it might completely lock genomes that contain the same values in different positions. For your example, with

```
g1 = {1, 4, 8, 9, 3, 2, 0, 0}
g2 = { 1, 3, 9, 8, 4, 2, 0, 0}
```

There would be no valid swaps at all, and the crossover would return the original genomes.

**Solution B**: If the value to be swapped is already present in the target genome, find the index of that gene in the target genome, and swap that too. This might cascade to require swaps in large parts of the genome, and of course it shouldn't happen when i=j.

Kind of depends on the desired behavior. For the example genomes above, what would a successful crossover look like?

Comment: I tried with "Solution A but the problem is the same. Before I tried with Solution B but it was even "worse"

Comment: It seems the problem is caused by a side-effect of "uniform crossover". However I'll try a bit more and I'll accept your answer for the effort

Comment: @dragonmnl: You could try to continue swapping as long as you get duplicates (change the `if(anyDuplicate...` to  `while(anyDuplicate...`), but that could take very long or might not terminate at all if no crossover without duplicates is possible.

Comment: In this end I solved rewriting the code from 0 and chanching few more things in the application .tank you very much for the effort!